# How to know device-type from JS Navigator object?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to know device type - ex: mobile, tablet from Navigator API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator?

Answer (score 2):

In a secure context, you can use [`navigator.userAgentData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData), which provides a [`NavigatorUAData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorUAData) object, which has some useful information about the user agent (browser), including a [`mobile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorUAData/mobile) flag. The [`getHighEntropyValues` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorUAData/getHighEntropyValues) returns a promise which will be fulfilled with more detailed information (if the user allows it) or rejected (if not, or the browser doesn't offer high-entropy values).

For platforms that don't support `userAgentData` (yet), you can fall back to parsing the `userAgent` string, but beware that the `userAgent` string is notoriously unreliable and easily spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
getDeviceType() {
        const ua = navigator.userAgent;
        const tabletRegex = /(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobi))/i;
        const mobRegex = /Mobile|iP(hone|od)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Opera M(obi|ini)/;

        if (tabletRegex.test(ua)) return "tablet";
        if (mobRegex.test(ua)) return "mobile";
        return "desktop";
    }
```

Comment: Relying on the user agent string is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: This will be useful if you want to support Safari (for ios and desktop) and Firefox because navigator.userAgentData isn't supported by them.  https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.userAgentData

Comment: Only if the user doesn't spoof it. :-) But it's worth mentioning as a fallback, yeah.